# Pascal: Store classes in a 2d array with New and Dispose

Tags: memory, new-operator, dispose, pascal

I'm trying Pascal, and I've defined my own class, `Block`. I have an `array[1..20, 1..20] of Block` called PlayGrid, now I'm trying to fill it with `Block`s.

This for loop:

```
for IterY := 1 to 20 do
    for IterX := 1 to 20 do

      //How do I put a new block instance in the PlayGrid?

      end.
    end.
```

Would you have to use New and Dispose to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
type
  TBlock = class    
     // You class stuff goes here
  end;

var 
  PlayGrid: array[1..20, 1..20] of TBlock;

begin
  for X := 1 to 20 do
    for Y := 1 to 20 do
      PlayGrid[X, Y] := TBlock.Create;
end.
```